# Compile separate document chapters into book w/o duplicate references?

Tags: chapters, book-design, combine

I am trying to collect a set of independent documents, each with its own preamble and
`begin{document}` and `\end{document}` lines into a book. I have looked into the `subfiles` package and tried `\include` but all of these require me to assemble a common preamble into a `main.tex` and then `\include` each of the file separately. The problem with this is that I lose the ability to **independently** compile each of the separate chapters because each chapters' preamble had to be removed as it was consolidated into `main.tex`. Thus, if I later want to compile each chapter separately, I have to replace the preamble and then compile. I would like to avoid doing this by hand because there are a lot of chapters.

Another problem is that each of the separate chapters has labels such as `fig:figure1`. There is no ambiguity when compiling each chapter separately, but when you combine them into one book they become ambiguous.

Is there a way around these problems?

Comment: have you looked at `pdfpages`?

Comment: I don't think that solves my duplicate referencing problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think it is good style to consolidate similar preambles. If, e.g., the subfiles define macros for special symbols in their preambles, it would be a good idea to outsource all such definitions into, say, `mysybols.sty`, that then can be loaded by all subfiles, and easily consolidated into a main preamble.

Apart from that, you might be looking for the `standalone` package. This package has the possibility to execute preambles of subfiles, see example below. Note however, that conflicting definitions or package options in the sub-preambles can not be resolved. This leaves the problem of multiply defined labels. I propose a hack that makes those labels unique by prepending the chapter number. For that, the definition of `\label` and `\ref` are altered. If you use other cross-referencing macros that don't fall through to `\label` and `\ref` like `\cref` from the `cleveref` package, they have to be treated in the same way. Note that redefinition of `\label` and `\ref` comes after `\begin{document}` here to have those redefinitions even after `hyperref` changed them.

Here are two small subfiles, both defining a macro, and both using a label `fig:1`.

`subfile1.tex` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\foo}{first subfile}

\begin{document}
\section{First section of \foo}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure of \foo}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{fig:1}.
\end{document}
```

`subfile2.tex` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\baz}{second subfile}

\begin{document}
\section{First section of \baz}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure of \baz}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{fig:1}.
\end{document}
```

Now the main document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\let\oldlabel\label
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{\thechapter:#1}}
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{\thechapter:#1}}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter including first subfile}
\input{subfile1}

\chapter{Second chapter including second subfile}
\input{subfile2}
\end{document}
```

If the sub-preambles are conflicting, and you really don't want to tidy that up, your best option is probably joining the pdf files with the `pdfpages` package, or even just pasting the pdf files together with a tool like `pdfjoin`. Note however, that with `pdfpages` you lose all hyperlinks from the sub-pdfs.

Comment: Good tip about redefining the `\label` command. Seems to work fine for me...